# Serving synchronous and asynchronous tasks in order (sequence) by using a $.queue()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some tasks that are synchronous and others asynchronous. They are mixed but I want to execute all of them in order.

Image i have below tasks synchronous: initialize, initiate, finalize, terminate
and below task asynchronous: task1, task2

I want them to be executed in the below order:
initialize, initiate, task1, task2, finalize, terminate

so how to it using a $.queue()? Below my implementation but it does not work.

Below the code of tasks:

initialize, initiate, finalize and termiate are "stupid" functions as they only print messages to the console log and to a div item.

```
function initialize(next) {

 // Here initialization stuff is done just before starting the entire process: things that are required later during the process
     console.log('Initiating process...');
     postStatus('</br>Initiating process...');

     next();
 }

 function initiate(next) {
     // Here enable/disable buttons are done
     setButtonDisabled(true);


     console.log('Process started.');
     postStatus('Process started <br/>');

     next();
 }


 function finalize(next) {
 // Here things required to be done just before terminating the entire process should be done.
 // Free resources, etc.
       console.log('Finishing process...');
       postStatus('<br/>Finishing process...');

       next();
 }

 function terminate(next) {
 // Here things that need to be done when the entire process finished.
 // Simple things such as those related to UI.
      setButtonDisabled(false);

      console.log('Process terminated.');
      postStatus('<br/>Process terminated.');

      next();
 }
```

The rest:

```
 function core(urlGetData, urlDoTask) {

 getTasks(urlGetData).then(function (response) {
            console.log("Response from getTasks: " + response);
             postResponse(response, "Received GetData results" + JSON.stringify(response));
            if ("fail" === response.status) {
               return fail(response);
            }

            console.log(response);
            return doTasks(response.data, urlDoTask);
      }).then(function () {
            postStatus("Received DoTask results");

            var results = arguments;
            console.log(results);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               postResponse(results[i], 'done ' + JSON.stringify(results[i]));
            }
      }).fail(function (err) {
            postStatus("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
 }

 function Task1(next) { 
         if ($('#Task1').is(':checked')) {
             core("/MyController/GetDataTask1/", "/MyController/DoTask1/");
         }

         next();
 }

 function Task2(next) {    
   if ($('#Task2').is(':checked')) {
         core("/MyController/GetDataTask2/", "/MyController/DoTask2/");
   }

   next();
 }
```

On button click I do:

```
  $({}).queue(initialize)
       .queue(initiate)
       .queue(Task1)
       .queue(Task2)
       .queue(finalize)
       .queue(terminate);
```

but It seems that they are not executed in order as in the console it is print in this order:

1. Messages for initialize
2. Messages for initiate
3. Messages for Task1
4. Messages for Task2
5. Messages for finalize
6. Messages for terminate
7. Shows task1 progress messages
8. Shows task2 progress messages
9. Shows task2 progress messages

   1. And so on... mixing task1 and task2 progress messages

because task1 and task2 are asynchronous.... so how to solve this? i want a non-blocking solution.

Output should be:

1. Messages for initialize
2. Messages for initiate
3. Execution Task1
   Shows progress messages for task1
   End execution Task1
4. Messages for Task2
   Shows progress messages for task2
   End execution Task2
5. Messages for finalize
6. Messages for terminate

How to queue all them (initialize, initiate, task1, task2, finalize, and terminate) in order they are executed in this order? Any piece of code will be highly appreciated....

I am using jQuery 10.1.2

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any need to use `$.queue` at all - I believe you should be able to do it all with `.then()`, e.g.

```
initialise().then(initiate).then(task1)...
```

Just ensure that your initial function returns a Promise.

Comment: I have tried a lot of solutions similar to this but none works as the problem is that Task1 and Task2 are asynchronous tasks... How to ensure initialise returns a promise?I guess returning $.Deferred().promise()? (I am very newbie in jQuery.Sorry).

Comment: @user1624552 yes, you can do `return $.Deferred().promise()`.

Comment: p.s. your `task1` and `task2` functions currently don't wait for the async `core` function to finish.  You need to make `core` return a promise too - the result of the chain of deferred calls within it would do.

Comment: I have put return $.Deferred().promise at the end of initialize() and core() functions and messages are not printed in order, for example, first messages fore initialize are printed and then messages for terminate are printed before messages for task1...

Comment: in `core` you should't return a new promise - return the one you're already creating when you call `getTasks().then(...)...` - note also that I haven't really looked _too_ much into the detail of the `core` function, but it looks like it has some `return` statements inside it that won't do anything useful (since it's an async function)

Comment: How do i have to return promise in core function? concatenating .promise()? doing this: return getTask(...).then(...).fail(...).promise(); ? sorry I am new in jQuery...

Comment: @user1624552 the latter, except you don't need to call `.promise()` on the end of the chain because `.fail()` already returns one.

Comment: so as i understand you no need to return promise in core function, right?

Comment: you do need to return a promise, but you don't need to create a new one.  Just add `return` on the front of `getTask()` !

Comment: ok sorry, I have added return in front of getTask() but I observe the same behaviour, I mean, messages are printed in order in the console, but as Task1 is asynchronous, after printing the last message for terminate, Task1 is continuing doing its jobs so functions called from within core, are printing messages for task1 after showing that entire process has terminated (by terminate function) and this is what I do not want.I want during executing task2, its messages get printed before the ones corresponding to terminate function.Messages printed by terminate function must be the last ones.

Comment: Even more, Task2 progess (if i append after task1 using then clause) which also call to core, its progress messages get mixed with the progress messages for task1 so task1 and task2 are executed concurrently that also it is what i do not want. Task1 must be executed first and once and only once task1 has finished, then task2 must be executed, and so on after function terminate is executed as the last one.

Comment: If task2 is starting too early then you must be somehow failing to always return an async promise from task 1.